# How to calculate tight bounds for asymptotic computational complexity for functions with subroutines?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I am faced with this question related to computational complexity and Big O notation. I am having a hard time understanding how the subroutines influence the total complexity of the functions. Do I consider the subroutine with the highest complexity as the upper tight bound of the function, or do I have to calculate a sort of combined complexity? Here is the question:

"The functions c and d call subroutines a1, a2 and a4 with the following computational complexities:

a1 = O(n), a2 = O(n<sup>3</sup>) and a3 = O(n log n).

```
void c(int n) {
        int z = 0;
        if (a1(n)+a2(n)*a3(n) > 1)
            z = 1 + a1(n);
       return z;
    }
    
void d(int n) {
        int i, j, s = 0;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            for (j=0; j<n; j++)
                s = s + a3(n);
        return s;
    }
```

Select tight bounds for the asymptotic computational complexity of functions **c** and **d**.

a) c = O(n<sup>6</sup> log n) and d = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

b) c = O(n<sup>4</sup> log n) and d = O(n<sup>3</sup> log n)

c) c = O(n<sup>3</sup>) and d = O(n<sup>3</sup> log n)

d) c = O(n<sup>4</sup>) and d = O(n<sup>3</sup> log n)

e) c = O(n<sup>3</sup>) and d = O(n<sup>2</sup> log n)

f) c = O(n<sup>4</sup> log n) and d = O(n<sup>2</sup>)"

Thank you in advance for the help!

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSl8A.jpg)

Comment: Let's work through C a little bit to get the idea. We see that `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` are all called once, potentially with an additional `a1` call. For simplicity, assume that optional `a1` call can be calculated once (since it could via compiler or by hand). Then the runtime is `O(n) + O(n^3) + O(n log n)` which is `O(n + n^3 + (n log n))`. With big-O notation, we care about the highest-order asymptotic bound, and `O(n^3) > O(n log n) > O(n)`, so C has a bound of `O(n^3)` (the other terms "fall off" / are irrelevant when taking `n` to infinity).

Comment: Following your methodology, the highest-order asymptotic bound for D should be O(n^3 log n), since we have a nested loop with O(n^2) complexity and subroutine a3 with O(n log n), and because if the fact that the subroutine is called from within the loops, we need to multiply the complexities together basically?

Comment: That'd be what I arrived at, yes. Rather than saying the loop has `O(n^2)` complexity, you can just note that your `O(n log n)` subroutine was called `n^2` times. So your complexity is `n^2 * O(n log n)` == `O(n^2 * n log n)` (as you arrived at).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that in

```
void c(int n) {
    int z = 0;
    if (a1(n)+a2(n)*a3(n) > 1)
        z = 1 + a1(n);
    return z;
}
```

there is no loop. To evaluate the function you have to evaluate each of `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` once and possibly evaluate `a1` once more. Since your evaluating each function basically once, the time complexity of the function comes down to the time complexity of the subroutine with the worst performance, `a2` which is O(n^3).

While in

```
void d(int n) {
    int i, j, s = 0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
            s = s + a3(n);
    return s;
}
```

you have a loop, that will iterate O(n^2) times, and in each iteration you are calling a function that takes O(n log n) time. We therefore multiply the time complexities yielding O(n^3 log n) (because we are going to be doing something that takes O(n log n) seconds, say, O(n^2) times).